# Passing parameters to template

Tags: c++, templates

I have this template:

```
template<class a>
    a multiply(a x, a y){
        return x*y;
    }
```

How can I pass different types of parameters? (int and float for example)

Comment: With the template you've provided, you cannot pass different types.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you want to achieve. You can specify the template argument explicitly (instead of letting it be deduced), which will cause the "mismatching" argument to convert to that type.

All examples in this answer assume `int i; float f;`

For example you can do this:

```
float res = multiply<float>(i, f);  //i will be implicitly converted to float
```

Or this:

```
int res = multiply<int>(i, f);  //f will be implicitly converted to int
```

Or even this:

```
double res = multiply<double>(i, f);  //both i and f will be implicitly converted to double
```

If you really want to accept parameters of different types, you'll need to handle the return type specification somehow. This is probably the most natural way to do it:

```
template <class Lhs, class Rhs>
auto multiply(Lhs x, Rhs y) -> decltype(x * y)
{
  return x * y;
}
```

Comment: After C++11, we can change the signature to `auto multiply(Lhs x, Rhs y)` or `decltype(auto) multiply(Lhs x, Rhs y)`

Answer (score 1):

just call the function as usual:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 3;
multiply(x,y);
```

Comment: I think he wants to call the function as `multiply(5, 4.4f)` for example.